# Using utopia and another roman font in (pdf)LaTeX

Tags: fourier

I need to create a document with Utopia (Fourier package) as the default font. 
However, at a certain point I need to change the default roman font to say for e.g. CM-Roman. At this point reverting back to utopia makes the text seem thicker and broader.

The MWE below illustrates my problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, draft]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\newcommand{\ffont}[2]{
     \fontencoding{#1}
     \fontfamily{#2}
     \selectfont
}

\begin{document}

Fourier-Utopia\\
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\
\ffont{OT1}{cmr}
Compuer Modern Roman\\
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\\

\ffont{T1}{put}
Fourier-Utopia Again\\
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\
\end{document}
```

This seems to happen only with the Utopia Font.
Can anyone let me know the correct way to achieve this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the font change local with putting it into `{...}`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, draft]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\newcommand{\ffont}[2]{%
     \fontencoding{#1}
     \fontfamily{#2}
     \selectfont}

\begin{document}

Fourier-Utopia\\
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

{\ffont{OT1}{cmr}
Compuer Modern Roman\\
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

Fourier-Utopia Again\\
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

the correct setting for fouriers roman font is `\ffont{T1}{futs}`

Comment: Thanks Herbert. From where did you get the correct font name as "futs", and what does "put" refer to in my original case, as it selects the utopia font. I ask because I got the name "put" from utopia.map and utopia.sty files.

Comment: I looked into the logfile `(/usr/local/texlive/2010/../texmf-local/tex/latex/fourier/t1futs.fd) [1{/usr/lo
...`